# Opengl - Compiling shaders on a different thread

Tags: multithreading, opengl, sdl-2, glew

For opening a thread I am using `SDL2` and for `opengl` I am using `glew`.

In my program, I have a thread in which I load and initialize all my resources. After doing a bit of research online I learned that a `GLContext` is only viable for the thread it was created on.

I could create another `GLContext` on my second thread, but then I won't have access to all the compiled shaders on my first thread.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just compile in the main thread. It's a quick process anyway.

Comment: i want to keep a smooth fps as much as possible.

Comment: Does that mean you're (re)compiling shaders when the program is already running, not just at the startup?

Comment: I made a loading screen so technically the program is running.

Comment: Then, did you actually get a slowdown when compiling on the main thread? I suspect that it would be unnoticeable, especially if you don't compile all the shaders at the same frame. If you insist on using a separate thread, look into GL context sharing. I'm not completely sure, but it could do what you want.

Comment: GL context sharing sounds good, I will take a look. thx :)

Comment: "After doing a bit of research online I learned that a GLContext is only viable for the thread it was created on." I don't know where this mis-information comes from. I read it several times now, but that doesn't make it true. The truth is that each GL conext can be current to at moste one thread at each point in time, but you can pass around a context between several threads as you like.

Comment: You should also be aware that a sensible driver will already use separate thread(s) for shader compilation, so your optimization does less then you thik, see [`GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_parallel_shader_compile.txt). Also note that drivers manage on-disk shader caches. Even mesa does this nowadays (for intel quite recently, though).

Comment: ok so how do I pass a GLContext to a different thread?

Comment: @RoyVaron `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(NULL)` (or another context) on first thread, then `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(ctx)` on second thread. Reverse when you finished with context on second thread. Baically you have to ensure context is not current on any other thread. Not sure it is very useful though, just use `ARB_paralle_shader_compile` if you can, driver will kick compilation on worker threads (or if you can't - at least don't query compilation status right after issuing compilation - driver can compile in parallel, but not if you ask it "I need the compilation result right now, I'll wait").

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)